# A counting argument involving triangle numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $T_n$ be the $n$th triangle number.

Use a counting argument to prove:

$$nT_1+(n-1)T_2+...+T_n={{n+3}\choose{4}}$$

Edit: to clarify I have already proven this using standard summation formulae, I am just wondering if there is a super slick way to prove this using the "double counting" combinatorics technique. I'm a novice at this and have only seen it used a couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  The right-hand side counts the number of four-element subsets of the $n + 3$ element set 
$$\{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n, n + 1\}$$
The left-hand side counts the number of such subsets whose second-largest element is $k$.  To make the argument work, you will need to show that 
$$T_k = \binom{k + 1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I am not satisfied with just seeing what the left side counts in just this case. How did you know that the left hand side was counting subsets by second largest element? And why choose to consider that particular set? These still seem like large leaps to me.

Comment: I decided to create the set in such a way that I could subsets by second largest element.  Each term on the left-hand side has the form $(n + 1 - k)T_k$.  I knew that $T_k$ counts the number of two-element subsets of a set with $k + 1$ elements, so I chose a set whose third smallest element was $1$.  If $k$ is the second largest element, then there are $n + 1 - k$ elements larger than $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (algebraic proof):
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i T_j=\sum_{i=1}^n {i+2\choose 3}={n+3\choose 4}.$$

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for but I welcome this elegant proof as well. :)